# How can I arrange for <input> and <textarea> inside a <div> to align to the top of the <div>

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div>
   <input>
   <input>
   <textarea>
<div>
```

What I would like is for the top of the input's and the textarea to all line up. However it seems like the inputs go to the bottom and the textarea to the top of the div. Is there a way I can fix this with CSS?

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x  input   input    textarea                        x
x                   textarea                        x
x                   textarea                        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: can you provide a snapshot of how you need?

Comment: **[Are you looking for this? - @Melina](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458770/how-can-i-arrange-for-input-and-textarea-inside-a-div-to-align-to-the-top/18458821#18458821)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align`:

```
div textarea, div input {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xg98S/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div>
   <input>
   <input>
   <textarea>
<div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
input{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
input,textarea
{ 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```